Cycling data updates
I have a view model
@MainActor
@Observable class SpenderGroupsViewModel {
    var spenderGroups: [SpenderGroup]?
    var isFetching: Bool = true
    
    private let networkManager = NetworkManager.shared
    
    init() {
        Task {
            await fetchGroups()
        }
    }
    
    func fetchGroups() async {
        guard !(networkManager.autCreds.auth_token ?? "").isEmpty  else {
            print("auth token is empty")
            self.isFetching = false
            return
        }
        self.isFetching = true

        
// here is some async load data logics
// function get a list of all user groups from API
// where if success there is fetching mark made false
                {
                    self.isFetching = false
                    print("fetching groups complete")
                }
    }
    
    
    func fetchGroup(spenderGroup: SpenderGroup) async {
        guard !(networkManager.autCreds.auth_token ?? "").isEmpty  else {
            print("auth token is empty")
            self.isFetching = false
            return
        }
        self.isFetching = true

        
// here is some async load data logics
// function get a detail information about one group from API
// where if success there is fetching mark made false
                {
                    self.isFetching = false
                    print("fetching groups complete")
                }
    }
}

and two views, one with group list
struct SpenderGroupsView: View {
    var viewModelCurrentUser : AuthViewModel
    @Environment(SpenderGroupsViewModel.self) private var viewModelSpenderGroup
    @Environment(FriendsViewModel.self) private var viewModelFriends
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if let user = viewModelCurrentUser.currentUser {
            NavigationView {
                //Text("hell world")
                List {
                    if let spenderGroups1 = viewModelSpenderGroup.spenderGroups {
                        if viewModelSpenderGroup.isFetching
                        {
                            ProgressView("Loading...")
                                .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        }
                        else {
                                ForEach(Array(spenderGroups1.enumerated()) ,id:\.offset) {(index, item) in
                                    NavigationLink(destination:
                                                    SpenderGroupDetailView(
                                                        spenderGroup: item)
                                                        .environment(viewModelSpenderGroup)
                                                        .environment(viewModelFriends)
                                    ) {
                                        SpenderGroupRowView(spenderGroup: item)
                                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                                    }}}}}
                .toolbar{
                    NavigationLink(destination:
                        SpenderGroupCreateView(viewModelSpenderGroup: viewModelSpenderGroup)
                            .environment(viewModelFriends)
                    )
                    {
                        Image("add-group")
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Groups")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                
                .onAppear() {
                    Task {
                        await viewModelSpenderGroup.fetchGroups()
                    }
                    print("onAppear")
                }
                .onDisappear() {
                    }
                }}}}}

and one with the detail view
struct SpenderGroupDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(SpenderGroupsViewModel.self) private var viewModelSpenderGroup
    @Environment(FriendsViewModel.self) private var viewModelFriends

    let spenderGroup : SpenderGroup
    
    var body: some View {
        let groupName = spenderGroup.groupName.capitalized
        if viewModelSpenderGroup.isFetching {
                    ProgressView("Loading...")
                        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } else {
            List {
                Section (header: Text("Expenses") )  {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ExpensesView(viewModelSpenderGroup: viewModelSpenderGroup, spenderGroup: spenderGroup)) {
                        HStack(alignment: .center ) {
                            Text(spenderGroup.groupName.prefix(1).uppercased() )
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                                .background(Color(.systemCyan))
                                .clipShape(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Circle()/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            
                            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
                                Text(groupName.capitalized)
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                Text("Something")
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            VStack (alignment: .trailing, spacing: 6) {
                                Text("Total")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                                Text(String(format:"%.2f",spenderGroup.totalAmount ?? 0))
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                Section (header: Text("Spenders") ){
                    HStack(alignment: .center){
                        Spacer()
                        let spenders = spenderGroup.spenders ?? []
                        NavigationLink(destination:
                                        SpenderGroupAddSpenders(selections: spenders,
                                                                spenderGroup: spenderGroup )
                                            .environment(viewModelFriends)
                                            .environment(viewModelSpenderGroup)
                        ) {
                            VStack(alignment: .trailing){
                                Image(systemName: "plus")
                            }}
                        }
                    if viewModelSpenderGroup.isFetching {
                        Text("Loading")
                    } else {
                        HStack(alignment: .center){
                            VStack (spacing: 12) {
                                if let spenders = spenderGroup.spenders {
                                        ForEach(Array(spenders.sorted(by: {$0.fullname < $1.fullname}).enumerated()) ,id:\.offset) {(index, item) in
                                            SpenderInGroupRowView(spender: item)
                                        }}}}}}
            }
            .refreshable {
                await viewModelSpenderGroup.fetchGroup(spenderGroup: spenderGroup)
            }}}}

When I try to refresh data in detail view then interface gets me back to SpenderGroupsView, and there is maybe 10 or more times fecth groups function started.
What is the correct way to transmit data between forms and dont get switching bewtween views?
What is the best way to load data first time and show a progress view, when this data is loading?
I expect that view is refreshing correctly when it is on top of screen and no other way

@Observable Is just for models. Move your async funcs into a controller struct and call them from .task and you can set the result either on State or on the model.
